# How to get OrderNumber in Sage Accpac after entering order with macro script

Tags: vba, vb6, accpac

I have recorded the process to create an order and quote in Sage ACCPAC, and i put the code in a VB 6 application, it works perfectly and adds a new quote / order. But what i need is that i want to get the generated ordernumber or orduniq within the same code , I want to perform some operations on that quote. But i am not sure, how can i get the information from accpac, as what i have done till now is simply recorded a macro and then copied the code and put it into VB application. I got the session creating code from a site, and made the Macro code dynamic and the application is ready to accept parameters and create an order on that basis , Kindly tell me how can i return the created ordernumber back to the user.

Thanks

Comment: Without code, you are asking people to write this for you, which is not the purpose of this site. Please post your current effort with a description of what difficulties you are having.

Comment: @King Khan. Could you please share your source code of creating order in sage ACCPAC.

Comment: @Ram , sorry don't have the code anymore , changed the company.

Comment: @KingKhan Ok..tnx for your reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agree with enterland - always good to post code here.  However, in this case I know what you're looking for.  Once you create the order you can get the order number from your order header view.  Along these lines:

```
OEOrderHeader.Insert
NewOrderNumber = OEOrderHeader.Fields("ORDNUMBER").Value
```